# Java Field<String> vs String

Tags: java, generics

What is the benefits of using Java `Field<String>` vs `String` except for the `cloneable` possibility?

We have a system that seems to use `Field<String>` here and there for no obvious reasons (into which I also put "we have done like that before").

Comment: Which `Field` do you mean? Specify the fully qualified path. Or is it a custom one?

Comment: You mean the reflection field vs a normal String? I don't get the question.

Comment: Are you allowd to use `Field` directly or do you have to `Field<Field<String>>` ... ouch, recursing into deep space ;)

Comment: Some kind of property effort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `Field<String>` is a *field* (concept) that can hold a `String` type value, while a `String` is just a `String`.

To understand the *why*, you'll have to look at the code (the oldest parts of the code base, where this class has been used). Maybe, they wanted to handle *database fields* via a common interface or base class. I wouldn't look for technical benefits (cloneing, performance, ...), there should be a design decision (at least, I hope, there is one).

Once you found the real reason, you can start to fighting all abuses of the concept (aka - "we always did it that way")